# Теперь за не принятую правку снимают репу?

Tags: дефект, правки, репутация

Сегодня смотрю помимо всего прочего `-2`. Думаю кто-то проголосовал против. Да нет никто не голосовал. А ссылка на `-2` [на вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/424048), который я недавно редактировал.

Теперь за не принятую правку снимают репу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что-то поменялось, видимо. Или баг.

Нашёл вот такой вопрос с ответом от сотрудника: [Репутация при откате не должна теряться](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142492/260198).

Задал на [MSE вопрос](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340384/260198) по этому кейсу.

Есть [вот такое обсуждение](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295028/260198):

> ...if the edit was previously approved, it will be marked Rejected and the previously-applied edit will be rolled back (complete with a comment in the revision history that describes what happened). If the editor earned +2 reputation for the edit, that will be retracted.

Если откатывает автор или модератор, то снимают `2` репутации.

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica задал на [MSE вопрос](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340384/260198) по этому кейсу.

Comment: Всегда так было: "Откат к версии 1 - Принятая правка отменена автором сообщения или модератором". Если  автор или модератор, то -2, а если кто другой, то репа оставалась. Поэтому часто просил модераторов откатить заведомо разрушительные правки, хотя мог и сам откатить.

Comment: @0xdb в случае с модераторами тоже?

Comment: Да, только если ТС или модератор, то откат репутации.

Answer (score 0):

Есть два варианта:

1. Вариант `@Suvitruf - Andrei Apanasik` (был сделан откат);
2. Вопрос, который вы правили, был удалён автором или духом сообщества;

А за отклонённые правки (то есть не вступившие в силу) репутацию **не вычитают**.